# why sql node can't not connect to mysql cluster?

Tags: mysql, centos7, mysql-cluster

I build a mysql cluster, one management node,two data node and two sql node。One management node in a centos server,one data node and one sql node in a different centos server,and the other data node and sql node in a third centos server。The management node and data node can start successfully.
[the cluster's status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvHUw.png)

Although I can start sql node,but it show that sql node can't connect to cluster.
I try to shutdown iptables.But it doesn't work.I have been stuck on this issue for two days.And I wish someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution. Although mysqld started,but it started as normal mode rather than in cluster mode.So I try to tell mysqld use "/etc/my.cnf" to explicitly start.Just like:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf
```

And it works!Yeah!!!